# Keras Library OR shall i choose neural network from Scratch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am new to deep learning.

We already have good libraries like Keras etc., to develop **neural network** application.

To develop deep learning models (apart from Keras) shall I also need to learn more about
 **neural network layer development from scratch.**

Following link is an example showing how to develop deep learning models from scratch. I am just assuming we can use Keras or other libraies to finish the task. Do we still need to learn this neural network from scratch to develop deep leaning models. Could you kindly tell something on this.

https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/deep-learning-deep-guide-for-all-your-matrix-dimensions-and-calculations-415012de1568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a beginner, I would rather suggest you to make neural networks from scratch and understand the basics of neural networks. You can use at the most numpy and pandas for this. In this way, you will learn the whereabouts of NN and won't mess up when you switch to DL frameworks.

It is not much difficult to make neural networks from scratch without any DL libraries.

After gaining significant knowledge about NN, you may then go for keras and other deep learning frameworks.

For any new skill always follow the path, basics -> practice -> intermediate -> advanced

Comment: Hi Amber, Thanks for Answering. Could you kindly tell one thing. When IT staff develop Deep neural networks for some applications, Do they develop neural network from scratch or Do they use some libraries and complete it.

Comment: They always use libraries as they are already trained in the basics of Neural Network. Also, if you can, please rate my answer and mark it as correct.